# How can I solve Hypergeometric function?

Tags: equation-solving

I have tried several ways to solve this equation (Hypergeometric) by `Solve` and `FindRoot`, and it still does not work.

```
0.717664 == -6.52609 + 38.1 (14500. a^2 + (-14.4 + 640. a - 8000. a^2 + 
    29629.6 a^3) HeavisideTheta[-0.09 + a] + (20. - 700. a + 
    8000. a^2 - 29629.6 a^3) HeavisideTheta[-0.075 + a] - 
 0.062069 HeavisideTheta[-(3/1450) + a] + 
 60. a HeavisideTheta[-(3/1450) + a] - 
 14500. a^2 HeavisideTheta[-(3/1450) + a]) + 2.64741*10^6 a^2 Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1.35098, 
2.35098, -7174.34 a^1.4804]
```

Does anyone know how to solve 'a' in this equation?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with your equation:

```
eq = 0.717664 == -6.52609 + 
   38.1 (14500. a^2 + (-14.4 + 640. a - 8000. a^2 + 
         29629.6 a^3) HeavisideTheta[-0.09 + a] + (20. - 700. a + 
         8000. a^2 - 29629.6 a^3) HeavisideTheta[-0.075 + a] - 
      0.062069 HeavisideTheta[-(3/1450) + a] + 
      60. a HeavisideTheta[-(3/1450) + a] - 
      14500. a^2 HeavisideTheta[-(3/1450) + a]) + 
   2.64741*10^6 a^2 Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1.35098, 
     2.35098, -7174.34 a^1.4804]
```

Get everything on the same side of the equation so we can plot to approximate a root.  Also convert to exact numbers, so we can get more precision in the answer.

```
expr = eq[[2]] - eq[[1]] // Simplify // Rationalize[#, 0] &
```

Plot our expression

```
Plot[expr, {a, 0, .01}]
```

It shows there is a root around `0.0016`.

Use `FindRoot` to solve.

```
FindRoot[expr, {a, 0.0016}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
(*   {a -> 0.0016737952551137831990061753853431893264697162736897}   *)
```

Test

```
expr /. %
(*   0.*10^-49   *)
```

Comment: _'convert to exact numbers so we can get more precision in the answer'_: if you assume that each number is rational you're throwing away the information that you have about the error in each number. I agree that when OP wrote $38.1$ they may have meant $381/10$, but assuming this and calculating the root to arbitrary precision is potentially misleading.

Comment: @Joe I won't argue about the value of error analysis, but in this case it is irrelevant because there is no indication that any of the numbers in the given equation represent experimental accuracy.  Some of the values used have only single digit precision and by default, Mathematica uses machine precision which may be too much for useful error analysis.  Using extra precision ensures that any errors in the result will not be due to excessive round off error.  Significant digits can always be reduced after you have accurately computed the result.

Comment: I don't think it's irrelevant, OP specified a problem and you made an additional assumption about that problem which you didn't state, it doesn't matter where the numbers come from. I think this assumption was reasonable and what you've written in your comment addresses it. If you put that in your answer it would be clear why you'd done it and what the limitations are, for example to someone who doesn't know very much numerical analysis.